# How to find bash commands?

Tags: linux, bash, find, command

I guess it's pretty simple.
I just want to locate a bash command. For example when I want to know which commands are existing, containing the phrase "user".

So the command I am looking for should print me wether the location of all commands containing user, or it could just tell me which commands exist with the name. That would be fine though.

I searched here in so and on google, but well both of them just talk about the "find" command.

Comment: This kind of questions belongs to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Are you talking about actual bash commands (built-ins), executable programs that you could execute with bash, the same but limited to ones in your `$PATH`, some combination of the above or something else?

Comment: No, not only limited to my $Path.
And by the way, Sampo, this was my first question. I read the faq of StackOverflow and it says here we could talk/ask about a programming problem. And this one is about bash programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of executable files or symlinks in your PATH that contain "user":

```
find $(echo $PATH | tr ':' ' ') -maxdepth 1 \( -type f -or -type l \) -name '*user*' -executable
```

sample output:

```
/usr/bin/users
/usr/bin/xdg-user-dir
/usr/bin/xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update
/usr/bin/users-admin
/usr/bin/xdg-user-dirs-update
/bin/fuser
/bin/fusermount
/bin/ntfs-3g.usermap
/usr/sbin/deluser
/usr/sbin/adduser
/usr/sbin/useradd
/usr/sbin/userdel
/usr/sbin/usermod
/usr/sbin/newusers
```

also a lot faster than wormsparty's variant (no offence :P). Result almost identical (his returns directories too, AFAIK)

Answer (score 1):

```
compgen -c | grep -i "user"
```

> compgen [option] [word]
>
> Generate possible completion matches for word according to the options, which may be any option accepted by the complete builtin with the exception of -p and -r, and write the matches to the standard output.
>
> The matches will be generated in the same way as if the programmable completion code had generated them directly from a completion specification with the same flags. If word is specified, only those completions matching word will be displayed.
>
> ### ...
>
> -A action The action may be one of the following to generate a list of possible completions:
>
> alias Alias names. May also be specified as -a.
>
> arrayvar Array variable names.
>
> binding Readline key binding names (see Bindable Readline Commands).
>
> builtin Names of shell builtin commands. May also be specified as -b.
>
> command Command names. May also be specified as -c.
>
> directory Directory names. May also be specified as -d.
>
> disabled Names of disabled shell builtins.
>
> enabled Names of enabled shell builtins.
>
> export Names of exported shell variables. May also be specified as -e.
>
> file File names. May also be specified as -f.
>
> function Names of shell functions.
>
> group Group names. May also be specified as -g.
>
> helptopic Help topics as accepted by the help builtin (see Bash Builtins).
>
> hostname Hostnames, as taken from the file specified by the HOSTFILE shell variable (see Bash Variables).
>
> job Job names, if job control is active. May also be specified as -j.
>
> keyword Shell reserved words. May also be specified as -k.
>
> running Names of running jobs, if job control is active.
>
> service Service names. May also be specified as -s.
>
> setopt Valid arguments for the -o option to the set builtin (see The Set Builtin).
>
> shopt Shell option names as accepted by the shopt builtin (see Bash Builtins).
>
> signal Signal names.
>
> stopped Names of stopped jobs, if job control is active.
>
> user User names. May also be specified as -u.
>
> variable Names of all shell variables. May also be specified as -v.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check for spaces in some path and improve it with more powerful regex, but this does the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 pattern"
    exit 1
fi

for x in `echo "${PATH}" | sed 's/:/ /g'`; do
    for y in $x/*; do
        if [ -x "$y" ]; then
            if [ `echo "$y" | grep $1 | wc -l` -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "$y"
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all commands in a directory, on Linux you can use:

```
find /bin -type f -perm -o+x  -name '*z*'
```

In this example, it will list all executables (programs) on /bin directory that had a z in their name. If you want to search in multiple directories, you can write a script and call the find in a loop, one time for each directory.

You can combine this with the previous answer to search in all directories on your path:

```
find $(echo $PATH | tr ':' ' ') -type f -perm -o=x  -name '*z*'
```

Comment: subdirectories of /bin are not in PATH. you won't find symlinks like this. for example, i have ``/usr/bin/dropuser -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper``. also, a loop is not necessary, see my answer.